# Regex - Match first and last character within capturing group

Tags: c#, regex

I want to capture the first and last character within a capturing group.

My current RegEx is -

```
([\w\.]+)@([\w]+)\.com
```

For example, if there is an email address -

```
xyz@test.com
```

This is the output -

```
Full match  0-12    `xyz@test.com`
Group 1.    0-3 `xyz`
Group 2.    4-8 `test`
```

The email address can have alphanumeric and period values.

If I want to curtail the Group 1 such that it starts and ends with only alphanumeric values, how to do that?

I want to modify this capturing group -

```
 ([\w\.]+)
```

The required output is -

```
xyz.@test.com Invalid
.xyz@test.com Invalid
xy.z@test.com Valid
```

Comment: Try `^(\w+(?:\.+\w+)*)@([\w]+)\.com$`. See live demo here https://regex101.com/r/KyUDuQ/1

Comment: Also note that `[\w]+` can be simplified to `\w+` - no need for a character set there.

Comment: `@"^\b[\w.]+\b@\w+\.com"$` will work, too.

Answer (score 2):

To tell engine match English alphanumeric characters at the start position and one before `@` you need to do this:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9][\.a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z0-9])@([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.com$
```

Note: `\w` includes `_` that you may not desire.

But this doesn't allow usernames with one character long. So you have to modify it a little:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:\.+[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)@([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.com$
```

Also this shouldn't be considered a good email validator. But as it seems you narrow down matching to `.com` TLD so I assume this is a very specific requirement otherwise it limits domain name to alphanumerics and doesn't allow many more characters that would be valid in an email address according to [RFC 822](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc822.txt). This would be enough for capturing an email address from user input:

```
^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+$
```

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
^([0-9a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_\.]*)(?<!\.)@([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\.com$
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pTjqpx/2)

Basically, it tries to match alphanumeric characters at the start, then `[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]` for 0 or more times. Before it reaches `@`, it will look behind to check if there is a dot (if it is not an alphanumeric, it's gotta be a dot).

Comment: You could reduce that lookbehind to `(?<!\.)`. Also `\w` in .NET [matches unicode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#word-character-w) letters too. You also could leave that dot unescaped.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex - (^[\w][\w\.\w]+[\w])@([\w]+)\.com